# Clearing eclipse cache for "referenced file contains error" problems

Tags: java, eclipse, castor

I use castor for xml binding/generation and this library works with mapping files.

The mapping files have the standart DOCTYPE header for castor.

```
<!DOCTYPE mapping PUBLIC "-//EXOLAB/Castor Mapping DTD Version 1.0//EN"    "http://castor.org/mapping.dtd">
```

In my eclipse installations, I get the following error

> Referenced file contains errors (http://castor.org/mapping.dtd)

What I tried (and did not work):

- Clear network cache in eclipse Prefs-General-Network Connections-Cache
- Changed eclipse version, using eclipse 3.8.2 now; same problem in both versions.
- Run eclipse with -clean option
- Copied the project to a new workspace

Any suggestions for an alternative hard reset?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The castor docs clearly states the usage of schema files here http://castor.codehaus.org/schema.html and it clearly states

> Mapping DTD -//EXOLAB/Castor Object Mapping DTD Version 1.0//EN http://castor.org/mapping.dtd

But when you click on the castor.org/mapping.dtd link on the [schema url](http://castor.codehaus.org/schema.html), it links to http://castor.codehaus.org/mapping.dtd

So, in fact, the correct dtd location is http://castor.codehaus.org/mapping.dtd , not  castor.org/mapping.dtd . This is clearly an ambiguity, but solves the "referenced file contains error" problem

Comment: codehaus doesn't exist anymore: "All Codehaus services have now been terminated." So where can we find a CDN castor.dtd or castor.xsd now?

Answer (score 1):

http://castor.org is (now?) a website with some meaningless drivel; perhaps it has been hacked. Open the http://castor.org/mapping.dtd link in a web browser to see...